# How to make a section of panel transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I happen to be trying to do the following:

[image]

A side menu with white background color, semi-transparent, but for example, if you click on an option (if selected) it becomes completely transparent allowing you to see the background image through it.

In the image, the Label1 option is selected, where the label box must be transparent, `Label1` must continue to be displayed and the rest of the panel must continue with its corresponding semi-transparent white color ...

Well, to achieve this I first tried drawing two boxes on the `Form`, but it turns out that the transparent is never drawn:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(25, Color.White));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, this.Height));

        var brush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush2, new Rectangle(0, 50, 50, 20));
    }
}
```

In addition to the previous problem, another problem with this method is that whenever I want to move the transparent position box, I would be forced to invalidate the control using `this.Invalidate();`

Then I decided to use a panel:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs ev)
    {
        base.OnLoad(ev);

        this.panel1.Paint += (s, e) =>
        {
            var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(25, Color.White));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, this.Height));

            var brush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush2, new Rectangle(0, 50, 50, 20));
        };  
    }
}
```

BUT... The result is the same...

In summary, the selected option must be completely transparent allowing to see the background image but leaving the label visible, and the rest must be semi-transparent white.

How can I do this?

Comment: As long as you don't try to make the form or parts of it semi-transparent this sounds quite doable (maybe even without drawing anything..) Instead of trying to draw tranparent why not make the panel transprent and draw opaque/semi-transparent parts.  (you can clip the trasparent part from the drawing graphics) - (( Or change the label backgroundcolors..))

Comment: Example: `int h = 30;  // use your numbers!!
Region r = new Region(new Rectangle(0,20+h, 40, 60+h));
e.Graphics.SetClip(r, CombineMode.Exclude);
using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(85, 255, 255, 255)))
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, panel4.ClientRectangle);`

Comment: @TaW Oh, this works, thank you very much